# ElasticSearch - Inner lucene file deletion hangs forever

Tags: java, elasticsearch, io, lucene, windows-server-2019

I'm using an ElasticSearch cluster in my Production environments for months now.
This cluster contains 2 nodes, which are Windows Server 2019 servers.

Sometimes, a random node of this cluster suddenly get stuck until i reboot the ElasticService, which is impossible by simply restarting the windows service. I need to kill the process to be able to restart it just after.

When I'm looking the threads contention, calling Elastic API, i'm getting this :

```
 0.0% (0s out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'threadDeathWatcher-2-1'
 10/10 snapshots sharing following 4 elements
   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
   io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Watcher.run(ThreadDeathWatcher.java:152)
   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

0.0% (0s out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'DestroyJavaVM'
 unique snapshot
 unique snapshot
 unique snapshot
 unique snapshot
 unique snapshot
 unique snapshot
 unique snapshot
 unique snapshot
 unique snapshot
 unique snapshot

0.0% (0s out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[PRODUCTION_CRITQUE_2][refresh][T#1]'
 10/10 snapshots sharing following 27 elements
   sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
   java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
   java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
   org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefreshBlocking(ReferenceManager.java:251)
   org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.refresh(InternalEngine.java:910)
   org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.refresh(IndexShard.java:632)
   org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.refresh.TransportShardRefreshAction.shardOperationOnReplica(TransportShardRefreshAction.java:65)
   org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.refresh.TransportShardRefreshAction.shardOperationOnReplica(TransportShardRefreshAction.java:38)
   org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncReplicaAction.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:494)
   org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncReplicaAction.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:467)
   org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShardOperationsLock.acquire(IndexShardOperationsLock.java:147)
   org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.acquireReplicaOperationLock(IndexShard.java:1673)
   org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncReplicaAction.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:566)
   org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
   org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReplicaOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:451)
   org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReplicaOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:441)
   org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69)
   org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$RequestHandler.doRun(TcpTransport.java:1544)
   org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:638)
   org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

0.0% (0s out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[PRODUCTION_CRITQUE_2][refresh][T#2]'
 10/10 snapshots sharing following 39 elements
   sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.DeleteFile0(Native Method)
   sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.DeleteFile(WindowsNativeDispatcher.java:114)
   sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:249)
   sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
   java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
   org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.privateDeleteFile(FSDirectory.java:373)
   org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.deleteFile(FSDirectory.java:335)
   org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.deleteFile(FilterDirectory.java:62)
   org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.deleteFile(FilterDirectory.java:62)
   org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreDirectory.deleteFile(Store.java:700)
   org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreDirectory.deleteFile(Store.java:705)
   org.apache.lucene.store.LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.deleteFile(LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.java:38)
   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.deleteFile(IndexFileDeleter.java:723)
   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.deleteFiles(IndexFileDeleter.java:717)
   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.deleteNewFiles(IndexFileDeleter.java:693)
   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.deleteNewFiles(IndexWriter.java:4965)
   org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter$DeleteNewFilesEvent.process(DocumentsWriter.java:771)
   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.processEvents(IndexWriter.java:5043)
   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.processEvents(IndexWriter.java:5034)
   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:477)
   org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:291)
   org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:266)
   org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:256)
   org.apache.lucene.index.FilterDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(FilterDirectoryReader.java:104)
   org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:140)
   org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:156)
   org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:58)
   org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.doMaybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:176)
   org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefreshBlocking(ReferenceManager.java:253)
   org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.refresh(InternalEngine.java:910)
   org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.refresh(IndexShard.java:632)
   org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.maybeRefreshEngine(IndexService.java:690)
   org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.access$400(IndexService.java:92)
   org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService$AsyncRefreshTask.runInternal(IndexService.java:832)
   org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService$BaseAsyncTask.run(IndexService.java:743)
   org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

0.0% (0s out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[PRODUCTION_CRITQUE_2][flush][T#4334]'
 10/10 snapshots sharing following 16 elements
   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.setLiveCommitData(IndexWriter.java:3116)
   org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.commitIndexWriter(InternalEngine.java:1562)
   org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.flush(InternalEngine.java:1063)
   org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.flush(IndexShard.java:780)
   org.elasticsearch.indices.flush.SyncedFlushService.performPreSyncedFlush(SyncedFlushService.java:414)
   org.elasticsearch.indices.flush.SyncedFlushService.access$1000(SyncedFlushService.java:70)
   org.elasticsearch.indices.flush.SyncedFlushService$PreSyncedFlushTransportHandler.messageReceived(SyncedFlushService.java:696)
   org.elasticsearch.indices.flush.SyncedFlushService$PreSyncedFlushTransportHandler.messageReceived(SyncedFlushService.java:692)
   org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
   org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69)
   org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$RequestHandler.doRun(TcpTransport.java:1544)
   org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:638)
   org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems that a delete file is locking (deadlocking ?) Elastic threads. I'm not deleting any index on Production so I guess it's an internal ElasticSearch process about Lucene when the replica node is trying to synchronize with the master node, it should delete Lucene segments that doesn't exist anymore or something like that ..

I tried speaking with the Elastic development team, but being stuck on a delete file seems, in their opinion, an environment issue more than an Elastic issue, which is undertanstable actually.

I stopped Antivirus and backup process on these servers, but still getting these locks like one time per month minimum.

How inner Java "DeleteFile" can hangs without returning any error or something. It just hangs forever, the server didn't seem to be under pressure at the same time.

If anyone has encountered this kind of issue, or have an idea to help me investigate, it would be awesome.

Thanks !

Comment: How are these 2 machines connected? Maybe one of them losing communication with other one and later coming back because you don't have an odd number for the cluster, it is becoming an issue.

Comment: It was our first track actually. Didn't find any clue on the ElasticSearch log .. I guess if a node is losing communication with the other one (we only have 2 nodes) we should find out some logs about that .. 
Technically speaking, i can't understand how a delete file could hang eternally actually ..

Answer (score 2):

Looks like others are experiencing this:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/massive-queue-in-refresh-thread-pool-on-a-single-node-causing-timeouts/280732/4

Have you looked at the Windows Event Viewer Application Logs to see if any windows process is giving any insight?

Looks like it is trying to remove old index files.

org.elasticsearch.index.shard.**IndexShard.refresh**(IndexShard.java:632)

Comment: I also see that there might be an issue if you have another instance that is reading (locking) the file attempted to be deleted.

Comment: Look at this to find which process is locking the file, if you can figure out which file it is.  
https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: I'm actually part of the ones who created the topic you mentionned.
I looked all the events in the Windows Event Viewer but nothing seems to be clearly related to my issue. 
I agree, it's look like hanging deleting old indexes or merging Lucene segments.
But, how an low level "DeleteFile" can hang like that ? How can i have anything on the ElasticSearch log ? That are questions i can't answer by myself ...

Comment: The issue with the link you posted about "finding the process which is locking a file", is that i simply don't know which file is locked here ..

Comment: Sorry it is hard to know exactly which file is locking and why, but I am guessing some other process has a lock on it. 

If you have the ability to run this in a dev environment, and are able to replicate it there, maybe you could try to enable more verbose logging for Lucene, like DEBUG or TRACE, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html 

From the link above: 

Other ways to change log levels include:

elasticsearch.yml:

logger.org.elasticsearch.discovery: DEBUG

This is most appropriate when debugging a problem on a single node.

Comment: We tried on our dev enrionment. Unfortunately, it seems hard to reproduce even when we're trying to "simulate" the load of our production environment. We don't exactly know the root cause so we just trying to run some load randomly and hoping for the issue to occurs.. Sorry i know it's not very useful to help investigating .. I will try harder to have a reproduce case i guess

Comment: Could it maybe be related to load on the system? Is there a way you can simulate load?

Comment: We made comparison of Production load when the issue occurs. It doesn't seem to have more pressure than the other days. We only do indexing and update, we don't do any delete on the indices/indexes. Our indices are "static" we always work on the same one. I guess that the "DeleteFile" that hanging is the result of some replication between our 2 nodes .. The only possible reason, on my level of comprehension, is that the disk is suddenly "full" during a replication and lock a random file from deletion .. Any other reason should probably made throw the DeleteFile, here it's not ..